# Generate excel report of specific row using check box in CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, codeigniter

as of now in my code i am able to generate excel report of entire table. I want to generate report of specific row using checkbox. i am not able to do this pls help me out.
From view function i get the table results from which i have to generate excel report of particular row using checkbox. I'm at the final stage of my project please help me out with this.

Thanks in Advance

[image]

**Controller:**

```
public function exportExcelData($records)
{
    $heading = false;
    if (!empty($records))
        foreach ($records as $row) 
        {
            if (!$heading) 
            {
                echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\n";
                $heading = true;
            }
            echo implode("\t", ($row)) . "\n";
        }
}

public function fetchDataFromTable()
{
    $query =$this->db->get('jc_meeting_expense'); // fetch Data from table
    $allData = $query->result_array();  // this will return all data into array
    $dataToExports = [];

    //Export To Excel
    foreach ($allData as $data) 
    {
        $arrangeData['Name'] = $data['name'];
        $arrangeData['Employee ID'] = $data['employee_id'];
        $arrangeData['Category'] = $data['category'];
        $arrangeData['Placename'] = $data['place_name'];
        $arrangeData['No of Employees'] = $data['no_of_employees'];
        $arrangeData['Claimed Amount'] = $data['claimed_amount'];
        $arrangeData['Amount per head'] = $data['amount_per_head'];
        $arrangeData['Meeting Date'] = $data['meeting_date'];
        $arrangeData['Expense Bill'] = $data['expense_bill'];
        $arrangeData['Other Expense'] = $data['other_expense'];
        $arrangeData['Other Expense Amount'] = $data['amount'];

        $dataToExports[] = $arrangeData;
    }
    $today = date("d.m.y");
    // set header
    $filename = "Employee Name ".$today.".xls";
    header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
    $this->exportExcelData($dataToExports);
}
```

**View**

```
<table class="viewjcexpense">
 <thead>    
 <tr>
    <th>Select</th><th>Name</th><th>Employee ID</th> 
    <th>Category</th><th>Place Name</th><th>No Of Employees</th> 
    <th>Claimed Amount</th><th>Amount Per Head</th>
    <th>Meeting Date</th><th>Expense Bill</th><th>Other Expense</th> 
    <th>Amount</th>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>

 <div class="scroll1">
 <?php foreach($query as $row): ?>
 <tr> 
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="<?php echo $row->name ?>"></td>  
    <td><?php echo $row->name; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->employee_id; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->category; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->place_name; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->no_of_employees; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->claimed_amount; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->amount_per_head; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->meeting_date; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->expense_bill; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->other_expense; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->amount; ?></td>
 </tr>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
 <tr>
    <td colspan="12" align="center">
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Generate Report" name="generatereport" formaction="<?php echo site_url('JcMeetingExpense/fetchDataFromTable'); ?>">
        </p>
    </td>
 </tr>
 </div>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check your data in the function `fetchDataFromTable`

something like

```
public function fetchDataFromTable()
{
    $arrRows = $this->input->post('checkbox[]');
    if (!empty($arrRows))   $this->db->where_in('id', $arrRows);
    $query =$this->db->get('jc_meeting_expense');
    ...
}
```

and in your view just put in your `id` as value in your `checkbox` element

```
<td><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>"></td>
```

That should pretty much do the job - assuming you did wrap your entire `table` in a `form`.

Comment: Hey i did the changes both in fetchDataFromTable and in my view. But now I'm getting this following error:                                                                                                   A PHP Error was encountered
             Severity: Notice

              Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$id

              Filename: JcMeetingExpense/jc_meeting_expense.php

              Line Number: 439

              ">

Comment: I solved the error, it was with multiple forms i just used formaction attribute with the site url. But again i'm getting all  the data except one particular row in excel.

Comment: take a look whats in your `checkbox` variable

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code.

**Controllers (welcome.php)**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
  public function index(){
    $query[] = array(
        'name' => 'empl_1',
        'employee_id' => 'empl_1',
        'category' => 'empl_1',
        'place_name' => 'empl_1',
        'no_of_employees' => 'empl_1',
        'claimed_amount' => 'empl_1',
        'amount_per_head' => 'empl_1',
        'meeting_date' => 'empl_1',
        'expense_bill' => 'empl_1',
        'other_expense' => 'empl_1',
        'amount' => 'empl_1',
    );
    $query[] = array(
        'name' => 'empl_2',
        'employee_id' => 'empl_2',
        'category' => 'empl_2',
        'place_name' => 'empl_2',
        'no_of_employees' => 'empl_2',
        'claimed_amount' => 'empl_2',
        'amount_per_head' => 'empl_2',
        'meeting_date' => 'empl_2',
        'expense_bill' => 'empl_2',
        'other_expense' => 'empl_2',
        'amount' => 'empl_2',
    );
    $query[] = array(
        'name' => 'empl_3',
        'employee_id' => 'empl_3',
        'category' => 'empl_3',
        'place_name' => 'empl_3',
        'no_of_employees' => 'empl_3',
        'claimed_amount' => 'empl_3',
        'amount_per_head' => 'empl_3',
        'meeting_date' => 'empl_3',
        'expense_bill' => 'empl_3',
        'other_expense' => 'empl_3',
        'amount' => 'empl_3',
    );
    $data['query'] = $query;
    $this->load->view('welcome',$data);
  }

  public function fetchDataFromTable(){
    // Here you will get the id of employee and on basis of you need to fetch data from DB.
    // var_dump($this->input->post('checkbox'));
    $data['selected_emp'] = $this->input->post('checkbox');
    $this->load->view('report_view',$data);
  }
}
```

**Views (welcome.php)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Simple CodeIgniter App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="<?php echo base_url('index.php/Welcome/fetchDataFromTable'); ?>" method="post">
        <table class="viewjcexpense" border>
            <thead>    
                <tr>
                    <th>Select</th><th>Name</th><th>Employee ID</th> 
                    <th>Category</th><th>Place Name</th><th>No Of Employees</th> 
                    <th>Claimed Amount</th><th>Amount Per Head</th>
                    <th>Meeting Date</th><th>Expense Bill</th><th>Other Expense</th> 
                    <th>Amount</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <div class="scroll1">
                    <?php foreach($query as $row): ?>
                        <tr> 
                            <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="<?php echo $row['employee_id']; ?>"></td>  
                            <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['employee_id']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['category']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['place_name']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['no_of_employees']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['claimed_amount']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['amount_per_head']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['meeting_date']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['expense_bill']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['other_expense']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['amount']; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="12" align="center">
                            <p> <input type="submit" value="Generate Report" name="generatereport"> </p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </div>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Views (report_view.php)**

```
<?php 
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet charset=utf-8");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Emp_List.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
?>
<table class="display" id="userListTbl">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Emp_ID</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach($selected_emp as $v){ ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $v; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It's working fine but in excel report i am getting only employeed ID of the checked row.... I need all records of that checked employee @Parth Viramgama

Comment: Read my comment properly which I already put in controller file .. where you need to write code to fetch record from DB and pass it to report_view file. Currently you got only ID because its just and dummy records for solving the issue.